# Why can't solcx find or use the compiler already installed?

Tags: python, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, solidity

I have installed solcx and installed the solidity compiler via the respective methods

`pip install py-solc-x`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install solc
```

However visual studio can not find my solidity compiler

When I run `solc --version` within my normal terminal I get
`solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface Version: 0.8.18+commit.87f61d96.Linux.g++`

However when i run
`compiled_contract = compile_files([{"path": filename, "content": contract_source_code}])`
The error message i get is

```
which: no solc in (/home/{USER}/Desktop/Ethernaut/venv/bin:/home/{USER}/.nvm/versions/node/v19.3.0/bin:/app/bin:/app/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/{USER}/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules/bin:/home/{USER}/.foundry/bin)
```

Even though when I run which solc it outputs the following (normal desktop terminal):
`/usr/bin/solc`

When I run solc within visual studio terminal it says the following:
`bash: solc: command not found`

I thought it was a permission issue and I changed the owner of the solc binary within `usr/bin` however that still not resolved the issue

Comment: Have you choose the correct python interpreter?

Comment: Yeah, my python interpreter is my venv that've set up. However, I have resolved the issue it seems to be a flatpack issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an issue regarding flatpak install of vs code. Reinstalled using a different packet manager.